# Git: restore my changes which were amended to merge commit

Tags: git-commit, git

I accidentally amended merge commit instead of creating new one. Now I don't know how to extract the changes to normal commit which I can push. The changes will show up in gitk, but will not appear in format-patch. Please, help.

Comment: depending on what you have done doing `git reset HEAD@{1}` might work.  Check with `git reflog` first.

Comment: Didn't work for me :(

Comment: What was the reflog output?  You should have be able to get a SHA for the original merge commit from it. depending on what you did it may be at a different position though.

Comment: My bad, it did work! It just unloaded much more changes than the method below. Though your method is more natural and easier. Do you want to create an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have 2 SHAs that are of interest here - the original merge commit, and the amended merge commit.  What you want to do is `git reset` your `HEAD` to the original merge commit, while preserving your index and working directory.  You can then create a new commit hanging off the merge commit.

Use

`git reflog`

to find the SHA of the original merge commit

reset to the commit with 
`git reset ORIGINAL_MERGE_COMMIT_SHA` or directly from reflog with `git reset HEAD@{X}` where X is 1 or the position in the reflog that represents the merge commit.

You should now be ready to `git commit` your original changes and don't pass in --amend here and you will create a new commit.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

- Get the SHAs of both the original merge commit and the amended merge commit
- `git reset --hard xxx` where `xxx` is the amended merge commit SHA
- `git reset --soft yyy` where `yyy` is the original merge commit SHA

That left me with my accidentally-amended changes staged.

Comment: This is imo the best- you don't have to dig in reflog, you don't have to rebase/patch, just take the changes and create new commit - possibly on new branch.

Answer (score 2):

I've found one way which works:

```
git diff HEAD~1 > p.patch
git checkout master
git checkout -b branch-name
```

Manually edit p.patch to remove unrelated changes from merge.

```
git apply p.patch
```

But I suspect there is a much easier/better way to do it.

Comment: Nice! I was trying with `git show > a.patch` but was then not possible to apply, with no help from git to explain what's the issue.